# MVC 3 html helper with a template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make a combination of a html helper and a Reder CSHTML.

In other words, how can I use a cshtml "template" with a html helper so I do not need to parse all the ugly HTML in the methods.

I am currently using @Html.Action but that is not preferable as it needs a working URL.

```
@Html.RenderAction("GetThreads", "Forum")

public ActionResult GetThreads()
{
    return new EmptyResult();
}
```

This gives the exception:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult
```

Do I always need to add a route in the Global.asax file? Or are there ways to call Actions without it (like HTML helpers, but with a template file).

Comment: What do you mean by: `html helper so I do not need to parse all the ugly HTML in the methods.`?

Comment: That I need a separate template file from the code logic, like in webforms the codebehdind files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@Url.Action` to get the URL of an action. I think that is what you need.

Or `@Html.RenderPartial` or `@Html.RenderAction` will spit out the view to the page.

`EmptyResult` won't render a view. That might be your problem.

You might be looking for `RenderPartial`.

Comment: I have been trying with RenderPartial, but I keep getting these errors: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult'

Answer (score 3):

> I have been trying with RenderPartial, but I keep getting these errors: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult'

Surround it with @{}

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("_SomePartial");}
```