# MVC4 Using nested @Html.RenderPartial() throws Compiler Error Message: CS1502

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razorgenerator

I am using MVC 4 and wanted to tidy up my views a bit so decided to create multiple partial views and bring them together during the rendering.

this works when the view being rendered has few  `@Html.RenderPartial('path\to\my\partialView.cshtml')` but fails if this partialView.cshtml is in turn has further `@Html.RenderPartial('path\to\my\otherPartialView.cshtml')` defined inside it.

i get errors like with using either RenderPartial or Partial method

```
error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments
error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult'
```

Is there a way in MVC4 we can achieve to tidy up my large view markup files? i.e. try to progressively compose the partial views with other partial views.

**EDIT**

Just to give more details.

My Mobile view looks like this:

File : ManageLoads.Mobile.cshtml

Location: Views->Shipper->ManageLoads

inside this view I have code like this:

```
<div id="landingPage" ng-show="MenuSelection=='DefaultPage'">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shipper/_DashboardPartial.cshtml")
            <div class='message {{MessageClass}}'>
                <i class='{{MessageIcon}}'></i>
                <p>{{Message}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

this part works fine without issue. now inside the _DashboardPartial.cshtml if I have reference to another partial view, it fails.

```
<div id="warehouseSelection" ng-show="getStep()==1">
   {@Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shipper/mobilePartials/_MyWarehouse.cshtml");}
</div>
```

this breaks and throws error, but if I copy paste the content of the "_MyWarehouse.cshtml" inside there, it starts to work again. I have verified that the path to the _MyWarehouse.cshtml is correct, so i suspected it has something to do with the nesting of the RenderPartial method that is causing the issue.

Regards
Kiran

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The first issue that I see is that your Html.RenderPartial syntax is incorrect.  The @ should be outside of the curly braces like so:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shipper/mobilePartials/_MyWarehouse.cshtml");}
```

Second, I wonder if the combination of `Html.Partial` and `Html.RenderPartial` is causing some issue here.  Try using both `Html.RenderPartial` with the syntax above to see if that fixes your errorl.

Comment: You made my day! I had been struggling with this for last few days without understanding what was happening. issue was with the @ placed at the wrong location inside {}. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have several options, like:

- use [custom html helpers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216736/asp-net-mvc-custom-html-helpers-in-razor) (for short general html code);
- use RenderPartial or RenderAction as it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310116/mvc-3-html-helper-with-a-template).

*(Also you should consider using rooted pathes like '~/Views/someController/etc/to/my/partialView.cshtml' or even moving your code to some shared views '~/Views/Shared/....'. But that's all upon you).*

**EDIT:**

Please, have a look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248183/html-partial-vs-html-renderpartial-html-action-vs-html-renderaction). It explains how exactly you should use mentioned methods. It must be rather in such way:

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("ViewName");  }
```

but

```
@Html.Partial("ViewName")
```

Comment: I din't think i fully follow your comment. When I call these functions on a partial views that is in turn built from other partial views, I get the errors. I works if I copy post the 2nd level partial view in to the 1st partial view.

Comment: I have used `@Html.Partial(...)` with no problems. Any exact reason you are using RenderPartial?

Comment: @Kiran Just added more info into the answer.

Comment: @Agat May be I was not clear, I don't have an issue with the syntax of these functions i have already followed same guidelines, issue is when I have one partial view that is build up of other partial views, and in that case when i try to render the topmost partial view, it throws error. is there a solution to this?

Comment: Well, I guess, you need to provide some more info of your hierarchy/structure, as embedded partial views just work generally, so there must be something specific in your situation.

Comment: @Agat : I have updated some more details on how the views are nested in my original post. - Regards

Comment: @siim : no particular reason, I am just doing trial and error in various combinations to see if any one of that actually works.

Comment: Ok. what's about the following: using this view name: `ManageLoads.Mobile.cshtml` without '.mobile'? Also, do the `_MyWarehouse.cshtml` have any model (or something) definitions in its header?